# pdo prepared inserts failing

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

I cannot get the code below to insert data.

```
<?php           
    $xml_gsm = null;
    try {
        // normally an include
        $data = new PDO(MYSQL_DSN, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
        $data->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

        $stmt = $data->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_sms_queue VALUES (fk_userId, fk_campaignId, message_content, gsm) VALUES (:userId, :campId, :message, :gsm);"); 
        foreach($gsms as $number):
            $xml_gsm .= "<gsm messageId='" . $data->lastInsertId() . "'>$number</gsm>";
            $stmt->execute(array(':userId'=>$userId, ':campId'=>$campId, ':message'=>$message, ':gsm'=>$number));
            print_r($data->errorInfo());
        endforeach;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }
?>
```

PDO errorInfo reports 00000 but nothing is inserted, the user has full crud permissions, $gsms is an array of numbers.

I have looked at other answers and nothing applies, i am now stuck on this one and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` instead of `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

I had:

```
$stmt = $data->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_sms_queue VALUES (fk_userId, fk_campaignId, message_content, gsm) VALUES (:userId, :campId, :message, :gsm);");
```

instead of:

```
$stmt = $data->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_sms_queue (fk_userId, fk_campaignId, message_content, gsm) VALUES (:userId, :campId, :message, :gsm);");
```